# Using putFileAs with an external file Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm looking to store an external file using `putFileAs` however I'm having some trouble.

Is it even possible?

**Note:** I don't want to `put` as an alternative. Because I want to specify the folder path.

```
$image = Storage::putFileAs(
    'images',
    'http://path.to/some/external/image.jpg',
    str_random() . '.jpg'
);
```

I get error

> Call to a member function getRealPath() on string

Edit: I edit my code as

```
$image = Storage::putFileAs(
    'images',
    file_get_contents('http://path.to/some/external/image.jpg'),
    str_random() . '.jpg'
);
```

But again I get an error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to a member function getRealPath() on string
at /home/vagrant/code/laravelapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php:222 

    218|     * @return string|false    
    219|     */    
    220|     public function putFileAs($path, $file, $name, $options = [])     
    221|     {  > 
    222|         $stream = fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r');
    223|    
    224|         // Next, we will format the path of the file and store the file using a stream since
    225|         // they provide better performance than alternatives. Once we write the file this
    226|         // stream will get closed automatically by us so the developer doesn't have to.
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you currently have to try and solve this issue? We can then help you.

Comment: I added my example code @GeorgeHanson

Answer (score 2):

Bug on [laravel 5.5](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/543).

Use **Storage::put** for contents of file.

```
$image = Storage::put(
    'images/'.str_random(). '.jpg',
    file_get_contents('http://path.to/some/external/image.jpg')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The FilesystemAdapter expects the second parameter to be a file and not a string. You used to be able to use `file_get_contents` and pass that in depending on your Laravel version. Please try this:

```php
$image = Storage::putFileAs(
    'images',
    file_get_contents('http://path.to/some/external/image.jpg'),
    str_random() . '.jpg'
);
```